# Proof of the strictly convexity of $|x^3|$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I am having problems proving that $|x^3|$ is strictly convex. As its second derivative is only non-negative (not strictly positive), it is not possible to prove it by this approach.

I've tried do it by the definition, but I couldn't do it.

Could someone give a hint on how to solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: The second derivative is strictly positive except at one point. Look at the _proof_ that $f''>0$ implies strict convexity and see if it still works, or can be made to work, if there's one point where $f''=0$.

Comment: You can also write $|x^3|=|x|^3$. This is the composition of two functions, the innermost one being convex. Try to apply the definition now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need only show $f(x,h)=\frac{1}{2}(|(x+h)^3|+|(x-h)^3|)$ is strictly greater than $|x^3|$ for all $h>0,x\in\mathbb{R}$.

For $x=0$ we have $f(x,h)=\frac{1}{2}(|h^3|+|-h^3|)=h^3>0$

For $x\ne0$:

$$\begin{align}
f(x,h)&=\frac{1}{2}(|(x+h)^3|+|(x-h)^3|) \\
      &=\frac{1}{2}(|x^3+3hx^2+3h^2x+h^3|+|x^3-3hx^2+3h^2x-h^3|) \\
      &\ge |x^3+3h^2x| &(\text{by the triangle inequality}) \\
      &=|x||x^2+3h^2| \\
      &>|x||x^2|=|x^3|
\end{align}$$

Hence $f$ is strictly convex for all $x$, as claimed.

Comment: Thanks!!!
The equation f(x,h) has a name?

Comment: Not really. It's just a two variable function that is the average of functional values at points that are equispaced on either side of $x$.